# Perl5 plugins for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, ide

I've tried to get an IDE for Perl 5 but with just while line

```
print "8";
```

it cycles many minutes and does nothing after all.

[image]

Comment: See also https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA

Comment: @HåkonHægland There is some strange directory with many items. Can you please explain to me how do I **run** a perl5 script saying `print "8";` ?

Comment: “Error running ‘Test Annotator’: Gradle project is untrusted, so it cannot be executed.” You need to make sure you installed and configure the Perl plugin first, then configure the project as being a Perl project.

Answer (score 6):

I tested this on Windows 10. First I installed the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA on Windows from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows). Then I opened the IDE and installed the Perl plugin as described [here](https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/wiki/Getting-started) :
[image]

Then configured the plugin by going to `Settings->Languages & Frameworks->Perl5` :

[image]

Click the cogwheel at the right side of `Perl5 Interpreter` and select your installed Perl exe (I am using Strawberry Perl):

[image]

Close the settings dialog and choose `File->New project..` and select Perl5 from the list:

[image]

click `Next` and then choose the Perl interpreter to use:

[image]

Choose a project name and its location:

[image]

Click the name of the project in the project view at the left side of the window, and choose `File->New->Perl5 file`. Type in the name of the script, and choose `Script` from the list :

[image]

Type in the `hello.pl` script in the editor:

[image]

Select `Run->Run..` from the menu, and click `Add new..` configuration:

[image]

In the dialog enter a new name for the run configuration, and enter the location of the script:

[image]

Then click `Run` and you should get output like this:

[image]